# Make Android Quiz Multiplayer

Tags: php, android, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

I have a Quiz App for Android, it has the API made in php.
It run good for one player, but I need to implement a multiplayer option, my idea is that one user send invitation to a friend, then this friend accept her invitation and the two mobiles start to the same time.

I'm googling and I know that I've to use a room of Google API, but is it true that I have to pay $ 25 to access GCM API?

For can access to API GCM credentials i have use this console (https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/) and make developer account...

It's okay? or i don' t understood well?

If i understood well, how can i implement the service that create a Room, i want say, When can i start googling?, if i didn't undestood well, could you explain to me how do?

Please a need help, i'm losing on this theme :(

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to access Google Play Developer Console, where you can Publish or Manage your apps, [you need to pay a one-time fee of $25](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6112435?hl=en).

The calls to the Google Play Games Services are free. Since you seem to be creating a real-time multiplayer, check the [Quick Game option](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#quick_game_option) for Android. However, if you're going to implement REST calls they have the [Get Started with Play Games Services for Web](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/gettingstarted) guide.

Comment: But for can call to API of Google Play I have credentials and for have this credentials I have access to Google Play Console no? so definitely I have pay 25 dollars? I'm wrong? (https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#client_id) I'm understand here that for Generate an OAuth 2.0 client ID (that is necessary for make the call to API) I have to access to Console, so I have pay 25 dollars, it's wrong?